# Only allow users to Register & Sign In with Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I am building an app and have Devise & Omniauth all set up with Twitter & Instagram login & registration working.

But what I am trying to do is similar to producthunt.com and only allow users to register & sign in with Omniauth (Twitter & Instagram) and not manually enter their email & password. Is this possible to disable manual registration? and keep Omniauth working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look in devise.rb initializer:

```
  # Tell if authentication through request.params is enabled. True by default.
  # It can be set to an array that will enable params authentication only for the
  # given strategies, for example, `config.params_authenticatable = [:database]` will
  # enable it only for database (email + password) authentication.
  # config.params_authenticatable = true
```

Comment: This will prevent signing in with email+password but won't prevent email+password registration.